# Detect changes in objects inside array in Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

Using Angular 2 and typescript. I have an array that I use DoCheck and IterableDiffer to listen to changes in my code. When the array is changed I get notifications, but when a property inside one of the objects in the array changes I don't get notified.
I tried using KeyValueDiffer but it doesn't work.
I think maybe I need to use the "_differs.find" differently.
Any ideas?

```
@Component({
    selector: 'test'
})
@View({
    template: `
    <div>hello!</div>`
})
export class MyComponent implements DoCheck {

private _differ: IterableDiffer;
private _differ2: KeyValueDiffer;
_myItems: MyItem[];
@Input()
set myItems(value: MyItem[]) {
    this._myItems = value;

    if (!this._differ && value) {
        this._differ = this._iterableDiffers.find([]).create(null);
    }
    if (!this._differ2 && value) {
        this._differ2 = this._differs.find(this._myItems).create(null);
    }
}
get myItems() {
    return this._myItems;
}

constructor(private _iterableDiffers: IterableDiffers, private _differs: KeyValueDiffers, private _myService: MyService) {
    this.myItems = _myService.getItems();
}

ngDoCheck() {

    var changes = this._differ.diff(this._myItems);

    if (changes) {
        changes.forEachAddedItem((record) => {
            console.log('added ' + record.item);
        });
        changes.forEachRemovedItem((record) => {
            console.log('removed ' + record.item);
        });
    }

    var changes2 = this._differ2.diff(this._myItems);
    if (changes2) {
        changes2.forEachChangedItem(
            (record) => {
                    console.log(record.key + "," + record.currentValue);
                }
            });
    }
  }
}
```

There is no way to get notified on changes in one of the properties of MyItem

Comment: Could you provide some code to show what you tried? Thanks!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In fact, you need to check differences for each object in the list not on the list itself. `KeyValueDiffer` must be applied on an object not on an array.

You could initialize an object containing all these `KeyValueDiffer` instances for the elements of your array:

```
constructor(private differs:  KeyValueDiffers) {
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.objDiffer = {};
  this.list.forEach((elt) => {
    this.objDiffer[elt] = this.differs.find(elt).create(null);
  });
}
```

Within the `ngDoCheck`, you need then to iterate over the `differ`s to check there are changes (for each item of the array):

```
ngDoCheck() {
  this.list.forEach(elt => {
    var objDiffer = this.objDiffer[elt];
    var objChanges = objDiffer.diff(elt);
    if (objChanges) {
      objChanges.forEachChangedItem((elt) => {
        if (elt.key === 'prop1') {
          this.doSomethingIfProp1Change();
        }
      });
    }
  });
}
```

See this plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/JV7xcMhAuupnSdwrd8XB?p=preview

Notice that I skipped the change detection for the array... But both can be done in parallel. Moreover when elements are added / removed the list of `KeyValueDiffers` should be updated accordingly.

Comment: What is the `.create(null)` part actually do?

Comment: It initializes the differ object with null. So the `diff` method can determine the  first difference (the complete object actually)...

Comment: Would you ever want to set this to anything other than null?

Comment: @ThierryTemplier How would you initialize the differ object with an existing object? `.create` requires `TrackByFunction<V>` as an argument..

Comment: how can you write this line `this.objDiffer[elt]` inside a loop when elt is an object, for each iteration elt.toString() will be equal to [Object, Object] so for each iteration, you will get the same result.

Comment: Is there any way to skip the iteration and directly check for a specific property?  Like a 'key exists' method?

Answer (score 3):

I found inspiration in Thierry Templiers answer but it did not work for me- I modified it and ended up with this solution:

You have this private variable:

```
 private objDiffers: Array<KeyValueDiffer<string, any>>;
```

You want to watch each element in an Array. In this case the array type is Array. The constructor should look like this:

```
  constructor(
    private differs: KeyValueDiffers) {
    this.itemGroups = new Array<ItemGroup>();
    this.differ = this.differs.find(this.itemGroups).create();
  }
```

ngOninit like this:

```
  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.objDiffers = new Array<KeyValueDiffer<string, any>>();
    this.itemGroups.forEach((itemGroup, index) => {
      this.objDiffers[index] = this.differs.find(itemGroup).create();
    });
  }
```

and ngDoCheck like this:

```
ngDoCheck(): void {
    this.itemGroups.forEach((itemGroup, index) => {
      const objDiffer = this.objDiffers[index];
      const objChanges = objDiffer.diff(itemGroup);
      if (objChanges) {
        objChanges.forEachChangedItem((changedItem) => {
          console.log(changedItem.key);
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

Now you will notice that each time an item within the array changes you will get a console log with that item and with the property that has changed.