# Angular2 - Iterable Differ doesn't detect change

Tags: typescript, angular

I'm using iterable Differs from Angular2 to detect changes on my data. Then I want to reload my view. But the differ.diff always returns "null" and I don't know why.

```
constructor(differs: IterableDiffers) {
    this.differ = differs.find([]).create(null);
}

@Input() data: any;

ngDoCheck() {
    var changes = this.differ.diff(this.data.datasets);
    if (changes && this.initialized) {
       //doreload
    }
```

EDIT:

```
this.pingService.pingStream.subscribe(ping => {
                  this.ping = ping;
                  console.log(this.ping);
                  NTWDATA.datasets[0].data.shift();
                  NTWDATA.datasets[0].data.push(this.ping);
```

PingService returns a number every 5secs(pinging my server). shift/push thingy works fine, data is there. It just doesn't get detected.
NTWDATA:

```
{
    labels: ["","","","","","",""],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: 'Server Response Time in ms',
            data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
            fill: false,
            borderColor: '#FF0303'
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Hard to tell. Please provide a Plunker that allows to reproduce.

Answer (score 6):

It depends on what you want to detect. With the `IterableDiffers` class, you will "only" detect if:

- elements are added in your array
- elements are removed from your array

But it won't detect if updates are done within elements of your array.

This question could interest you:

- [Detect changes in objects inside array in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35748484/detect-changes-in-objects-inside-array-in-angular2/36268847#36268847)

See this plunkr for the use case: https://plnkr.co/edit/wn6mTEcvrW2vh1ko5Ji5?p=preview.

Comment: First I use shift to remove first element, then I do a push. So actually both cases.

Comment: I made a test with your use case and it seems to work. See this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/wn6mTEcvrW2vh1ko5Ji5?p=preview.

Comment: I see. In my case I'm changing the datasets[0].data. When I set the changes to "changes= this.differ.diff(this.data.datasets[0].data)" my changes get detected and it works. But this is only a workaround as it won't work for other datasets within my NTWDATA. Any ideas on how to make it more "general"?

Comment: The problem is that differs only support one level and not the complete data graph. For recursive support, you need to implement it by your own...

Comment: @Thierry Templier Seems that IterableDiffers, beside the two situations you mentioned in the answer, also detects the element's instance change.