# angular2 detect changes in ng-content

Tags: javascript, angular

Is there a way to detect changes in ng-content?

```
@Component({
    selector: 'example',
    template: `<ng-content></ng-content>`
})
export class Example {}

@Component({
    selector: 'test',
    template: `
        <example>
            <div *ngFor="let el of elements">{{el}}</div>
        </example>`
})
export class Test {
    elements = [1, 2, 3];

    ngOnInit() {
        setInterval(() => this.elements[0] += 10, 3000);
    }
}
```

I would like to get some information in Example class when my ng-content will change.

Here is [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/ao4PVeogOCBPuFqTVPC4?p=preview)

Comment: Your plunker is working fine for me. I guess I'm not sure what you're looking for.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to detect changes each time when my ng-content will change.

Comment: Related/duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42962394/angular-2-how-to-detect-changes-in-an-array-input-property ... Your `elements` array always points to the same object in memory, regardless whether its contents change, so you cannot just use `onChange()`. Use `IterableDiffers()` as explained in the linked answer.

Comment: @mc01 totally unrelated to the question you linked to. Here we're talking about changes to ng-content, not inputs.

Answer (score 26):

The easiest solution is to use the [cdkObserveContent](https://material.angular.io/cdk/observers/overview) directive.
First, you must add to the imports of the module that owns the component ObserversModule

```
import {ObserversModule} from '@angular/cdk/observers';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    /* ...other modules you use... */
    ObserversModule
  ],

/* ... */
})
export class MyModule { }
```

Then in your component's template:

```
<div (cdkObserveContent)="onContentChange($event)">
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

The event will trigger each time the content inside changes somehow and the value passed to the function is an array with all the details about what changed. The value of the data that has changed can be found in `target.data`.

In your component.ts:

```
onContentChange(changes: MutationRecord[]) {
   // logs everything that changed
   changes.forEach(change => console.log(change.target.data));
}
```

Also, you can use as a service that gives you an `Observable<MutationRecord[]>`

Comment: I think this is the best solution in 2020. `ngAfterContentChecked` can fire too many times, it could hurt performance.

Answer (score 9):

My solution for a project is to monitor the content's innerHTML. This example is from a tooltip that shows template content. I don't really like this solution, and would be happy to have a different/better one offered. This will emit whenever there are changes.

```
/// tooltip.component.html
<div class="tooltip" [class.hidden]="hidden">
    <div #content>
        <ng-content></ng-content>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
///tooltip.component.js
import { AfterContentChecked, AfterContentInit, Component, ElementRef, EventEmitter, Output, ViewChild } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: "example",
    templateUrl: "./tooltip.component.html",
    styleUrls: ["./tooltip.component.scss"]
})
export class TooltipComponent implements AfterContentInit, AfterContentChecked {    
    @ViewChild("content") contentWrapper: ElementRef;
    content = "";
    @Output() public readonly contentChanged = new EventEmitter<string>();

    ngAfterContentInit(): void {
        this.content = this.contentWrapper.nativeElement.innerHTML;
        this.contentChanged.emit(this.content);
    }

    ngAfterContentChecked(): void {
        const c = this.contentWrapper.nativeElement.innerHTML;
        if (c !== this.content) {
            this.content = c;
            this.contentChanged.emit(this.content);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works but runs on every change anywhere in the project no matter where

Answer (score 8):

To detect changes in `ng-content` assuming you're adding a `ItemComponent`.

**The code would be:**

```js
import { QueryList, ContentChildren, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

export class TestComponent implements AfterViewInit  {

    @ContentChildren(ItemComponent)
    public itemList:QueryList<ItemComponent>;


    public ngAfterViewInit() : void {
        this.itemList.changes.subscribe(() => {
            // put your logi here
        });
    }

}
```

**Notes:**
According the [ContentChildren documentation](https://angular.io/api/core/ContentChildren) you have to wait `ngAfterViewInit` to access the `QueryList` so you can not use it on `ngOnInit`.

See the [QueryList documentation](https://angular.io/api/core/QueryList) to see all the other properties that this class provides you.

Answer (score 2):

Use AfterContentChecked interface:

```
constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) { 
}
ngAfterContentChecked():void{
  this.cd.markForCheck();
}
```

for more information take a look at https://angular.io/api/core/AfterContentChecked

Answer (score 0):

I've come to a solution but I think this might not fill well for everyone needs. First of all treat nested components childs (after all, ng-content is nothing more than that) is very easy on React world and I think that it would be very nice to have a more robust solution for Angular too.

My solution is based on Material Angular Icon, the code you'll find here: 
https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/icon/icon.ts

Following MatIcon approach, I wish to create an icon component where the name of desired icon is passed by ng-content like arrow-top.

Therefore I wish to observe whenever ng-content changes so that I can update the span classname.

**The solutions is simply linking the data present into ng-content to an @Input followed by a getter.**

Thus, whenever the ng-content changes Angular will update its component input too.

Hope this looks clear.

```
@Component({
 selector: 'fa-icons',
 template: `
 <span #templateRef class="template">
  <ng-content></ng-content>
 </span>

 <span [className]="iconName" [ngStyle]="ngStyle">
 </span>
 `,
 styles: [`
   :host > span.template {
     display: none;
   }
 `]
})
export class FaIconsComponent {
 @ViewChild('templateRef') templateRef: ElementRef;
 @Input() name: String;
 @Input() ngStyle: StyleSheetList;
 @Input()
 get iconName() {
   const text = this.templateRef.nativeElement.textContent.trim();
   return `fa-${text}`;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to complete something every time bound data updates you can use the `ngOnChanges()` lifecycle hook. Check out the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks), for more info.