# How to print parent value inside child component in angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new in angular4

I have an Registration process which contains multiple steps, So I am just `hide/showing` my steps of the basis of some conditions.
So, Registration process contains parent and child component("sidebar" that show the value that user filled in last step).

I am passing a array from parent to child. And in each step I am updating my array with some values.
When I'm printing my array in child HTML its working fine but when I trying to console the same array in child compenent.ts its showing nothing.
I have to do some calculation like in my arary I have date of birth so I want to calculate the actual age of user and show the same on sidebar.

This is my array: MyArray
This is how I am passing my array

Parent.html

```
<app child [MyArray]="MyArray"></app child>
```

ChildComponent.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit,Output,Input } from '@angular/core';
export class SidebarComponent implements OnInit {
     @Input() MyArray: string;

     ngOnInit() {
     console.log(this.MyArray,'ssss');     
}
}
```

If I use MyArray.email in my child.html then Its showing the value fine.

Anyone having any Idea What I am doing wrong here

Comment: I wonder how it works when you put Myarray.email where MyArray is a string

Comment: You can omit ":string" if you want. You don't have to declare it. Or you can declare as array as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are passing an array from your parent component to child, your input must be declared as array in your child component , if you really not sure about the type , you can put it as any

```
  @Input() MyArray: Array<any>;
```

and you can access the particular property using the index or using ngFor in the template

```
console.log(this.MyArray[0].email);
```

if you need to watch for the changes on array, you can use **`ngOnChanges`**

> Respond when Angular (re)sets data-bound input properties...Called
>   before ngOnInit() and whenever one or more data-bound input properties
>   change.

```
ngOnChanges(changes) {
    // code here
}
```

Comment: ok, but my question is at any point if my array is update then how can I get the array value in  child component. Right now I am able to get the value in child HTML but not in component

Comment: Inside ngOnInit() I am consoling the array, But its showing nothing.

Comment: it should be available in the component as well. can you produce a demo

Comment: ngOnInit gets called only when the component gets called, so if you are looking for updated value it wont be there

Comment: Yes, That is my question how can I get the update value everytime?

Comment: you need to use need onChanges on input, let me edit the answer

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42962394/angular-2-how-to-detect-changes-in-an-array-input-property

Comment: I have use ngOnChanges still not getting the array in component

Comment: @Rahul If you read the picked answer from the above link, you'll notice the solution involves `ngDoCheck`, not `ngOnChanges`. The latter only works if the property itself changes, but in your case it's still the same array, only its content change, hence why you need to do the former.