# How to trigger html method from type script

Tags: angular

As a continuation to this question:

[angular primeng p-table pagination not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52871879/angular-primeng-p-table-pagination-not-working)

I need a way to trigger html method from TypeScript. In the example in the question I need a way to run

```
table.reset()
```

from my TypeScript. The reason for that is that my current component is called whenever a different link is used (a menu) and each time the displayed is changed.
I have learned that in order to init the paginator fields, I need to use the `reset()` method - BUT my problem is how to trigger this change.

For the first time there is no problem because I added it to the GET button I have but when the menu is used again I don't want to press the get button (I am triggering changes in the display using

```
ngAfterContentChecked()
```

Comment: Get a reference to the table using a `ViewChild`, and you can call the function using that

Comment: thank you I am new to angular never new about this option I have read about it and using the help of @dirtyMind it is now working for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose this is your table:

```
<p-table #tt [value]="testdata" class="test-data" [lazy]="true"
         (onLazyLoad)="loadDataLazily($event)"
            [paginator]="true" [rows]="3" [totalRecords]="totalRecords">
```

To reset it in component file : use it like below:

```
import { Table } from '../../../../node_modules/primeng/components/table/table';
    export class TableComponent{
     @ViewChild('tt') tt: Table;
     resetTable(){
      this.tt.reset();
     }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for you help !! it is working fine for me now