# view is not updating after pushing new object into array angular 7?

Tags: javascript, angular, twitter-bootstrap, typescript

app.component.ts

```
   import { Component, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from './api.service';
import configData from './apiConfig.json';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {

  data: any = [];
  finalResponse: any = [];
  isLoadingResults = true;
  apiConfig = configData;
  private _apis: any = [];


  constructor(private api: ApiService, private ngZone: NgZone) {
  }

  // ngOnInit() {
  //   this._apis.push({name: "getRefills"});
  // }

  getMemberInfoCache(tokenId) {
    console.log(tokenId);
    this.api.getProducts(tokenId)
      .subscribe((res: any) => {
        /** @namespace res.details.cacheobject.specialtyMemberInfo **/
        this.data = res.details.cacheobject.specialtyMemberInfo;
        console.log("testDATA" , this.data);
        this.isLoadingResults = true;
      }, err => {
        console.log(err);
        this.isLoadingResults = false;
      });
  }
  loadApis(tokenId) {
    /** @namespace this.apiConfig._apisJson.getRefillsRequest **/
    const getRefillRequest = this.apiConfig._apisJson.getRefillsRequest;
    console.log("GETREFILLS", getRefillRequest);
    if(getRefillRequest) {
      // this._apis.push({name: "getRefills"});
      // console.log("INSIDE IF", getRefillRequest);
      this.ngZone.run(() => { this._apis.push({name: "getRefills" }); })
    }

    return this._apis;
  }


}
```

app.comp.html

```
<div class="card-body">
              <div class="container">
                <table class="table table-striped">
                  <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Api</th>
                    <th scope="col">Request</th>
                    <th scope="col">Status</th>
                    <th scope="col">Action</th>
                  </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                  <tr *ngFor="let item of _apis">
                    <td>
                      {{item.name}}
                    </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: are you sure element is pushed into _apis? any error from console?

Comment: Possibly relates to or is answered by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42962394/angular-2-how-to-detect-changes-in-an-array-input-property

Comment: yes i added log inisde if statement and its printing the object

Comment: The method `loadApis` maybe called outside of Angular zone. Try: `this.ngZone.run(() => { this._apis.push({name: "getRefills" }); })`.

Comment: The code itself works, must be something else you are not showing here

Comment: what else could be there , loadApi's triggered and printing all the object now _apis object should bind to view

Comment: @hussain, how is _apis defined (@Input etc)? what is changedetection strategy (OnPush) etc?

Comment: @ABOS i am new to angular 2 + i have added all the code in question

Comment: @hussain - Did you try my suggestion? :-)

Comment: @ConnorsFan i tried it did not work as you can see in updated question

Comment: @hussain, I don't see where you called loadApis

Comment: It may be caused by `this` being wrong. Try defining `loadApis` as an arrow function: `loadApis = (tokenId) => { ... }`.

Comment: @ConnorsFan did not work with arrow function