# Angular View not updating Data

Tags: angular

I am new to angular programming so bear with me if my question is not well structured.I m trying to create a simple food ordering app, So i have a service while take mock data from a json file and it also have some methods which manipulates the data.

```
import { Injectable, FactoryProvider } from '@angular/core';
import { groupBy, remove, find } from "lodash";
import { foodItems } from "./food-items.constants"
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {
      private foodz = foodItems;
      private cart = [];
      private CartObject = {};
      private totalAmount: number = 0;
      constructor(private router: Router) {

      }
      getTotal() {
        return this.totalAmount;
      }
      getCart() {
        return this.cart;
      }

      getFoodItems() {
        let items = groupBy(this.foodz, function (food) {
          return food.cuisine;
        });
        return items;
      }
      addItemToCart(item) {
        let cartItem = find(this.cart, function (cartObject) {
          if (cartObject.itemName === item.itemName) {
            cartObject.quantity++;
            cartObject.Amount = cartObject.quantity * item.pricePerUnit;
            return true;
          }
        });
        if (cartItem) {
          this.totalAmount += Number(item.pricePerUnit);
          alert(this.totalAmount);

        }
        if (!cartItem) {
          this.cart.push({
            'itemName': item.itemName,
            'quantity': 1,
            'Amount': item.pricePerUnit
          });
          this.totalAmount += item.pricePerUnit;
          alert(this.totalAmount);

        }
        return true;
      }
      removeItemFromCart(item) {
        let cartItem = find(this.cart, (cartObject) => {

          if (cartObject.itemName === item.itemName) {
            if (cartObject.quantity == 1) {
              this.totalAmount -= item.pricePerUnit;
              alert(this.totalAmount);
              remove(this.cart, function (cObject) {
                if (cObject.itemName == item.itemName) {
                  return true;
                }
              });
            }
            else {
              cartObject.quantity--;
              cartObject.Amount = cartObject.quantity * item.pricePerUnit;
              this.totalAmount -= item.pricePerUnit;
              alert(this.totalAmount);
              return true;
            }
          }
        });
        if (!cartItem) {

        }
        return true;
      }
}
```

Next i have a component which has an instance of this service through DI and through users actions i am trying to add and remove foods in my cart.
**Issue**
While my cart is updating right but the `total` variable is not being updated on the fly as soon as i add or remove items from the cart.
Here is my component.ts file contents.

```
      import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
  import { DataService } from '../data.service';

  @Component({
    selector: 'app-add-card',
    templateUrl: './add-card.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./add-card.component.css']
  })
  export class AddCardComponent implements OnInit {
    private cart = [];
    private total: number;

    constructor(private foodService: DataService) {

    }

    ngOnInit() {
      this.cart = this.foodService.getCart();
      this.total = this.foodService.getTotal();

    }
  }
```

and here is my view component.html file to display cart summary.

```
<div class="menu text-center" > <br>
 <h1><span>{{ total | currency: "INR" }}</span></h1 > <br>
</div>
< br >

<div class="menu" style = "margin-bottom: 30px" >
  <div class="heading text-center" >
    <span>Order Details < /span>
  </div>


  < div class="item" * ngFor="let item of cart" >
        <span style="width:50%;display:inline-block" > {{ item.itemName }}</span>
        <span style = "width:20%;display:inline-block" > Qua.{ { item.quantity } } </span>
         <span > {{ item.Amount | currency: "INR" }} { { cart.total } } </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz with a live demo, so that we can edit it ? https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: okay i will do it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2: How to detect changes in an array? (@input property)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42962394/angular-2-how-to-detect-changes-in-an-array-input-property)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will not update because you are not listening to the changes done in the `total` value in the service.

Add a Subject for the total value in your service, components can subscribe to the changes in the subject and accordingly update their variables.

In your service, have something like:

```
public totalObs = new Subject()
```

Wherever you update your total in the service do this:

```
this.totalObs.next(this.total)
```

In your component have something like:

```
totalSub: Subscription
ngOnInit() {
   this.cart = this.foodService.getCart();
   this.totalSub = this.foodService.totalObs.subscribe((total) => {this.total = total}); 
}

ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.totalSub) {
        this.totalSub.unsubscribe()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution, i will try this and get back to you. just a supplementary question: how is my cart updating then on the fly as soon as i add or remove items from the cart. i haven't written anything for that but it seems to update without me writing anything.

Comment: @GaganDeep Please show the component code you have written for updating the cart, (both HTMl and ts)

Comment: that component simply just calls the service method like `this.foodService.addItemToCart(item);` thats it. i send the item to it from the html. and it adds it to cart and my view is updated instantaneously.

Comment: @GaganDeep `cart` is an Array, its reference is shared between the component and the service Whenever you do things on the browsers (clicks for add/remove), a change detection will run and will check for existing data. Same should happen for `total` but `total` is a primitive type, its reference is not shared between the component and the service so the changes done in the service will not affect the changes in the component.

Comment: ok. Thank you @xyz i will try this when i have my laptop with me and get back to you on this. Thank you for your efforts.

Comment: This did solve my issue. Thank you very much @xyz , I really appreciate your support.