# Angular Typescript changing Object property in array not updating view

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm working on learning Typescript and Angular and I have question as to why my view isn't updating when updating an array value that is set to a object i have defined. I suspect it's something to do with me losing the context to this? Do I need to run ngZone somehow? (I've tried with no success). I suspect this it's something easy or a concept I'm overlooking.

```
cardItems = {
  addUser: true,
  inventory: false
}
cardCollapseItems = [
{
  label: "addUser",
  item: this.cardItems.addUser
},
{
  label: "inventory",
  item: this.cardItems.inventory
},

collapseCard(value){
 let index = this.cardCollapseItems.findIndex(item => item.label === value)
 let cardItem = this.cardCollapseItems[index]
 cardItem.item ? cardItem.item = false : cardItem.item = true;
}

 <ion-card-header (click)="collapseCard('addUser')">
 <ion-card-content [hidden]="cardItems.addUser" >
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2: How to detect changes in an array? (@input property)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42962394/angular-2-how-to-detect-changes-in-an-array-input-property)

Comment: Stop learning Angular for a bit and go learn RxJs. Angular is a different style of programming built on RxJs and reactive programming. In modern JavaScript apps we don't modify data structures any more we push new ones created off the old ones. Make sure you have a good understanding of RxJs before even looking at Angular. I wish somebody told me this a few years ago.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I will dive deeper into RxJs. I use it some already and coming from Knockout I have a decent understanding of observables and subscriptions, but I thought that was overkill for this situation, I guess not!

Comment: it's as expected, value of cardItems is not being changed. so obviously there wont be changes in html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

One:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-example-page',
  templateUrl: './example.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./example.page.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
```

Two:

```
public cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef;

public constructor(
    cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef,
  ) {
    this.cdRef = cdRef;
  }

collapseCard(value){
 let index = this.cardCollapseItems.findIndex(item => item.label === value)
 let cardItem = this.cardCollapseItems[index]
 cardItem.item ? cardItem.item = false : cardItem.item = true;
 this.cdRef.detectChanges();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply i'll try implementing something like this. Any reason this strategy is worse or better than using RxJs?

Comment: If you are going to use ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush then you really don't want to be mutating data like arrays. You should be constructing a new array with the changes. Modern JS is a different world than it used to be.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to displaying `cardItems` in your view. you have to update it from the `collapseCard` function. Updating with `this.cardItems` will solve the issue.
You are assigning true or false to value which is only limited to your intialized variable in function.

Comment: Yes I originally went this route and it worked, but i wanted to be able to just update my array when I created new items that way the collapseCard function doesn't need updating.