# How to update array in another component?

Tags: angular

I have data response as object:

```
let response = {
   attachments: [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}]
}
```

I use this data in root component `<app-root></app-root>`

```
<app-documents [response]="response"></app-documents>
<app-attachments [response]="response"></app-attachmnets>
```

Inside component `app-documents` I try to update response:

```
response.attachments.push({id: 4});
```

But in `app-attachments` component that uses the same `response` object is not changed.

How to fix it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 2: How to detect changes in an array? (@input property)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42962394/angular-2-how-to-detect-changes-in-an-array-input-property)

Comment: No, I need to detect chnages in another component, so I can to add `response` to service then share service bettwen components

Comment: This halped me `  this.application.attachments = [].concat(this.application.attachments);`

Comment: You use your array on input, so to get changes you need to make it on output too : https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you are making an unilateral assignment to your `response` variable. I.e. `app-attachments` `response` won't detect changes made in another component.

You can either:

1. Use some state management tool like `ngrx` which I think it is not the better solution for you right now because it requires redux knowledge and has a significant boilerplate;
2. Use a simple service wich allows you to share your `response` across components.

Example:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ResponseService {
  responseSubject: BehaviorSubject<any>;

  constructor() {
    this.responseSubject = new BehaviorSubject(null);
  }

  getResponseValue(): any {
    return this.responseSubject.getValue();
  }

  setResponse(response: any): void {
      this.responseSubject.next(response);
  }

  addItem(item: any): void {
    this.responseSubject.next([...this.responseSubject.getValue(), item]);
  }
}
```

For usage in your components:

```
// Get current response array value
let response = this.responseService.getResponseValue();

// Set response value(for example, when you receive it from an API)
this.responseService.setResponse([{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}]);

// To push new item to attachments array
this.responseService.addItem({id: 4});
```