# Angular 7: Onchanges not triggered for child component in 1 case

Tags: angular

I have used a child component in my parent component. Child `onchanges` is triggered first time through `ngoninit`. But when i trigger onClick function , Child `onchanges` does not get triggered. What am I doing wrong?

```
<app-child [inputData]="data"></app-child>
```

ParentComponent :

```
{
    data = [];

    ngOnInit() 
    {
        this.data = [1,2]
    }

     onClick()
    {
        console.log("clicked");
        this.data = [3,4];
    }

}
```

ChildComponent:

```
@Input inputData;

ngOnChanges(changes:SimpleChanges) 
{   
    console.log("change detected xxxxxxx");
}
```

NOTE: Instead of `this.data = [3,4]`, I also tried `this.data.push(3)`, still no change

Comment: Are you using the `onPush` change detection?

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara I am using default. I have not explicitly set any

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though both the answers provided good learning, but I fixed it by cloning existing array and calling `detectChanges`

```
this.data = Object.assign([], [3,4]);          
this.cdr.detectChanges();
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason because you are not getting the catch in the `ngOnChanges` on your child's component is because you are changing the value in the `data` variable and not its reference.

Implementing `ngDoCheck` and `IterableDiffers` can be a solution, more details can be found here: [Angular 2: How to detect changes in an array? (@input property)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42962394/angular-2-how-to-detect-changes-in-an-array-input-property)

Another way to solve this problem could be to use `JSON.parse`:

```
onClick() {
  this.data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify([3,4]));
}
```

My personal opinion is to not use `NgDoCheck` since it's really heavy on memory.
I would personally use a `Subject` in order to trigger the update of the `child component`.

**Ideal service:**

```
@Injectable()
export class YourService {
  private _$forceRender = new Subject<boolean>();
  public onForceRender = this._$forceRender.asObservable();

  public setForceRender(): void {
    this._$forceRender.next(true);
  }
}
```

And then on your `onClick` function:

```
onClick() {
  console.log("clicked");
  this.data = [3,4];
  this.myService.setForceRender();
}
```

Finally in your `child` component:

```
  constructor(
     ...
     _cdr: ChangeDetectionRef,
    ...) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
      this.myservice.onForceRender.subscribe(() => {
        this._cdr.detectChanges();
      });
    }
```

More details about `ChangeDetection` [here](https://medium.com/@sciampi.jacopo/angular-performances-a-guide-to-change-detection-b8a02c0b7b00)

Comment: even I change existing reference, e.g. `this.data.push()`, it didn't work in my case.

Comment: `push` method does change reference. It just add an element.

Comment: I mean, as you mentioned  "The reason because you are not getting the catch in the ngOnChanges on your child's component is because you are changing the value in the data variable and not its reference." , so changing the value in reference by push method should have worked , right ?

Comment: `push` method only mutates the array and no new reference is created, I've edited my answer with a third _method_ that can solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to make it in **immutable** way, so that you notify Angular's change detection as this is the easiest way. You can do it like that:

```
 onClick()
{
    console.log("clicked");
    this.data = [3,4];
    this.data = this.data.slice();
}
```

For further information, you can check [immutable operations you can make with arrays](https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/all-about-immutable-arrays-and-objects-in-javascript).

Comment: I am getting error : `Expected at least 1 arguments, but got 0.ts(2555)
lib.es5.d.ts(1286, 12): An argument for 'start' was not provided.` I guess in newer releases , no arg splice() is not there

Comment: It should be slice() instead of splice().

Comment: thanks, changed to slice() but change detection still didn't work