# ngOnChanges doesn't trigger for angular 2

Tags: angular

I have a child component as a pagerService which gives us pageBounds every time I give it a length of array I need to be paginated.

This is how I pass the length of the array to be paginated to the child component from the parent component:

```
<!--parent -->
    <ng-container *ngIf="currentView.tasks && currentView.tasks.length">
            <span>{{currentView.tasks.length}}</span>  <!--for debugging -->
            <pagination-bar [totalItems]="currentView.tasks.length" (onTotalItemChanged)="setPageBounds($event)" >

            </pagination-bar>
        </ng-container>
<!--/parent>
```

This is my child component :

```
@Component({
selector: 'pagination-bar',
  template: `<ul *ngIf="pager.pages && pager.pages.length" class="pagination">
                <li [ngClass]="{disabled:pager.currentPage === 1}">
                    <a (click)="setPage(1)">First</a>
                </li>
                <li [ngClass]="{disabled:pager.currentPage === 1}">
                    <a (click)="setPage(pager.currentPage - 1)">Previous</a>
                </li>
                <li *ngFor="let page of pager.pages" [ngClass]="{active:pager.currentPage === page}">
                    <a (click)="setPage(page)">{{page}}</a>
                </li>
                <li [ngClass]="{disabled:pager.currentPage === pager.totalPages}">
                    <a (click)="setPage(pager.currentPage + 1)">Next</a>
                </li>
                <li [ngClass]="{disabled:pager.currentPage === pager.totalPages}">
                    <a (click)="setPage(pager.totalPages)">Last</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
`,
})
    export class PagerService implements OnChanges{
      @Input()
      totalItems:number;
      @Output()
      onTotalItemChanged = new EventEmitter<any>();
      pageBounds : any;
      pager : Pager;

      constructor() {
      }

      //this is never called
      ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
        this.pager = this.getPager(this.totalItems);
        this.pageBounds = {
          startIndex: this.pager.startIndex,
          endIndex: this.pager.endIndex
        };
        this.onTotalItemChanged.emit(this.pageBounds);
      }


      getPager(totalItems: number, currentPage: number = 1, pageSize: number = 10) :Pager {
        let pager:Pager ;
        // some logic.. hidden as irrelevant to the question


        return pager;
      }
    }
```

The currentView is changed in the parent which in turn is triggered by the route.navigate as:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.workbenchBaseUrl = this.propertyService.configData && this.propertyService.configData.workbenchBaseUrl || null;
    this.route.params
        .switchMap((params: Params) => {
      let id = params['id'];
      if(!id){
        this.router.navigate(['/view', this.taskViewService.getDefaultViewId()])
      }
      return this.taskViewService.getView(id);
    })
      .subscribe((view: TaskView) => {
      this.currentView = view;
      this.taskViewService.refreshViewContent(this.currentView);

    });

  }
```

I read similar questions including this one: [Detect changes in objects inside array in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35748484/detect-changes-in-objects-inside-array-in-angular2)

Which got me thinking maybe ngOnChanges is not trigger as it doesn't change the input instance but I'm not sure of that hypothesis,

I read about ngDoCheck([DoCheck](https://angular.io/api/core/DoCheck) )  but don't completely understand it or even if I need to use it in my case

Comment: It's a little bit weird you didn't provide @Component and provide source for a class named PagerService which hint to a service and not at all a component. But again this code use Input and Output used only in component. So if it's really a service the behavior is completely normal.

Comment: It is a  component , I didn't provide the compoenent part of it as I thought It might be irrelevant , I have added it now

Comment: Is the setPage function removed as well?  I'm not seeing that function on the component.

Comment: @JosephKing yes , it basically emits an event event which call a function int the parent to change the page ,i hidden it  for now

Comment: `ngOnChanges` is only called for template expressions bound to `@Input()` properties. Are you sure your `*ngIf` resolves to `true`?

Comment: I check the span in the html and it gets the correct length so yes, it does go inside the if-block

Answer (score 1):

This is probably stupid ,but I should post it before someone else waste their time like me . 
I had forgot to put the child component in the appmodule declarations