# How to detect which object in array has changed property value?

Tags: angular

I have an array of objects. User can change value of some property in that array of objects. What i want to detect which object has changed. I musing `iterableDiffer` but i dont know how to display only those that are changed. Any suggestion ?

```
   let changes = this.iterableDiffer.diff(this.workorders);
        if (changes) {

       }
```

Comment: take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35748484/detect-changes-in-objects-inside-array-in-angular2/36268847#36268847