# Get array size changes in Angular 8 using IterableDiffer

Tags: javascript, angular, iterable, angular2-changedetection

I have angular component with array of Objects

```
export class AlertsConfigListComponent implements OnInit, DoCheck {
@Input() config: ProductAlertConfig[];
```

And using IterableDiffer to get changes of this array:

  `constructor(private iterableDiffers: IterableDiffers) {
    this.iterableDiffer = iterableDiffers.find([]).create(null);
  }`

```
ngDoCheck(): void {
let changes : IterableChanges<ProductAlertConfig> = this.iterableDiffer.diff(this.config);
if (changes) {
  this.doSmth();
}
```

}

It works and I can get changes every time when array is changed.
So now my question is. How to check in **changes** object that array's size is changed, because it is triggered also when I sort this array. There are no properties in **IterableChanges** object for this purpose.

If I could get new size of array I would do that:

```
ngDoCheck(): void {
let changes : IterableChanges<ProductAlertConfig> = this.iterableDiffer.diff(this.config);
if (changes && newSize !== oldSize) {
  this.doSmth();
}
```

}

And it would fix the problem, but are there any other solutions?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35748484/detect-changes-in-objects-inside-array-in-angular2/36268847#36268847

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detect changes in objects inside array in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35748484/detect-changes-in-objects-inside-array-in-angular2)

Comment: No I don't think that this is what I need because the problem in example is that they are going to get each value inside array and check property changes. But what I need is to check when element is added or deleted from this array

Comment: try this :- this.iterableDiffer = iterableDiffers.find(this.config).create();

Comment: i have added my answer below. and a working stackblitz with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if there is a direct method. One workaround would be to check if there are elements added/removed to the array by abusing `forEachAddedItem` and `forEachRemovedItem` methods and `try`/`catch` block. Try the following

```js
ngDoCheck(): void {
  let changes: IterableChanges<ProductAlertConfig> = this.iterableDiffer.diff(this.config);
  let lengthChanged: boolean = false;

  if (changes) {
    try {
      changes.forEachAddedItem(item => {
        if (item) {
          lengthChanged = true;
          throw 'Array length changed';           // break from the `forEach`
        }
      });

      if (!lengthChanged) {                       // proceed only if `lengthChanged` is still `false`
        changes.forEachRemovedItem(item => {
          if (item) {
            lengthChanged = true;
            throw 'Array length changed';         // break from the `forEach`
          }
        });
      }
    } catch (e) {
      // pass
    }

    if (lengthChanged) {
      this.doSmth();
    }
  }
}
```

---

<sup>Try/catch is used here deliberately to break from the `forEach`. Commenting about it would help others/later</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Problem is with your constructor.

```
constructor(private iterableDiffers: IterableDiffers){
   this.iterableDiffer = iterableDiffers.find(this.config).create()
}
```

Working Stackblitz :- https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uqivci

Comment: It is working fine. But my question is inside ngDoCheck() how can I check that size of array is changed. I mean Item is added or item is removed but skip this check for the time when we first time initialize array with values

Comment: on push and pop its working, you need on length change? if a element is getting added or removed. that means length is changing. can you give a example what do you want?

Comment: like in my above example i have callback to eachaddeditem, you can add to eachremoveditem. in these callbacks you get your array length? Previous Array length will be current length - number of items you receive in callback?